# How to correct set "Boundary" into java.net.http.HttpRequest header

Tags: java, java-11

### I tried to use **HttpClient** and **HttpRequest** from JDK11 to send a Multipart file to the server:

```
public static int sendMultipartFile(String uri, Path filePath) {
    HttpClient httpClient =`enter code here` HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .build();

    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(uri))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofFile(filePath))
            .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .setHeader("Boundary", "gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p")
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    return response.statusCode();
}
```

### Server endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/api/logs/throw")
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("logs.7z") MultipartFile file) {
    Path path = Paths.get("/home/terminal_logs/");
    storageService.store(file, path);
}
```

### Following error occurs in the server side:

> ERROR 17072 --- [nio-8081-exec-2]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
>   request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found] with
>   root cause

### How to set header properly to avoid this errror?